# How to keep the status of the ViewHolder in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which includes a few grid cells. There is a TextView above CLICK ME button. I'll show something for example, the name at the TextView when button is clicked. The problem for me is the text inside the TextView is not persistent.

Here is my code in MainActivity:

```
private void initializeData(){
    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("Name 1", "23 years old", R.drawable.a));
    persons.add(new Person("Name 2", "25 years old", R.drawable.b));
    persons.add(new Person("Name 3", "35 years old", R.drawable.c));
    persons.add(new Person("Name 4", "35 years old", R.drawable.c));
    persons.add(new Person("Name 5", "35 years old", R.drawable.c));
    persons.add(new Person("Name 6", "35 years old", R.drawable.c));
    persons.add(new Person("Name 7", "35 years old", R.drawable.c));
    persons.add(new Person("Name 8", "35 years old", R.drawable.c));
    persons.add(new Person("Name 9", "35 years old", R.drawable.c));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView  = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    initializeData();

    RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(persons);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Code in my adapter:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder>{

List<Person> persons;

RVAdapter(List<Person> persons){
    this.persons = persons;
}

@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cards_layout, viewGroup, false);
    PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
    personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
    personViewHolder.personAge.setText(persons.get(i).age);
    personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);

    final PersonViewHolder vh = personViewHolder;
    personViewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vh.textView.setText(vh.personName.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return persons.size();
}

public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    public TextView personName;
    public TextView personAge;
    ImageView personPhoto;
    public TextView textView;
    public Button button;

    PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        personAge = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
        personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        button = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    }
}
}
```

I think the reason is the ViewHolder is recreated. How to deal with this kind of situation? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a boolean `isShowName` to your model `Person`, then in your `onBindViewHolder()` method:

```
...
personViewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        vh.textView.setText(vh.personName.getText().toString());
        persons.get(i).setIsShowName(true); // don't forget!
    }
});

if (persons.get(i).isShowName()) {
    vh.textView.setText(vh.personName.getText().toString());
} else {
    vh.textView.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the boolean field to the object corresponding to each cell and set this value for true when user clicks the button, then add the logic to `onBindViewHolder()` method:

```
if (clicked) {
    showText();
} else {
    hideText();
}
```

Also change `vh.textView.setText(vh.personName.getText().toString());` to `personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);` inside your OnClickListener - you have to keep and request data only by using `List<Person> persons`, not from the ViewHolder, because adapter reuses views and when you'll request data from ViewHolder you'll get data previously inflated Views

Comment: Sorry. That's not the point. For example, there are 9 cells in my case. I clicked all the buttons from 1-9 in sequence. But the text in cell 1,2,3 are **Name 7**, **Name 8** and **Name 9**. Apparently they are modified by the click of cell 7,8,9.

Comment: change `vh.textView.setText(vh.personName.getText().toString());` to `personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);` inside your OnClickListener